# SQLAlchemy, attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an API that I built using python fastAPI that pulls from a sqlite database using sqlalchemy, and it works fine in dev but after I deployed it I'm getting--

qlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database

The code right now is--

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///./etfs.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args = {'check_same_thread':False})
```

How do I connect to the database so that it isn't read-only? Or how do I create the database in sqlite so that it isn't read-only to begin with?

Comment: Check that the program in fact has permission to write to `etfs.db`, and ensure that [`PRAGMA query_only`](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_query_only) is not enabled.

Comment: Could it also be that the process does not have write permissions to the actual file?

Comment: What is the syntax to check PRAGMA_query_only?